# Aligning an input with a button in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, alignment

I'm having trouble aligning a regular `<button>` beside an input in Firefox. I get the following output in Firefox:

[image: Output in Firefox]

The input class is university and the button class is next and the CSS code is the following:

```
.university {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    padding: 20px;

    width: 400px;
    display: block;

    border: none;

    color: #000;

    border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;

    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline-color: #000;
}

#next {
    background-color: #C44D58;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    width: 150px;

    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;

    color: #FFF;

    border: none;

    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;

    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline-color: #000;
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<div class="universityContainer">
    <input type="text" class="university typeahead" placeholder="University Name">
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

The CSS for `.universityContainer` is:

```
.universityContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Note:** It should be noted that it renders correctly in every browser except for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: block` from the `.university`.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gf9Tr/

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/tJdvqfw.png) is the result of removing `display: block;`

Comment: You can try using `vertical-align: middle` for both the `.university` or the `#next`.  Or, provide more code.  Because, removing `display: block` makes both elements align in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: P.S. It's a good practice to provide a jsfiddle with the effect that you are observing.  Makes it easier to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Could it have something to do with typeahead.js?

Comment: @Shazer2 Does typeahead.js by any chance change the styles on these elements?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Just removed the call of `.typeahead()` in my js file and it now renders correctly in FF.

Comment: @Shazer2 Sounds like you should look into what the actual styles on those elements end up being after that call in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `display: block;` or you can use `display: inline-block;` in class university instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `display:block` on the `input` element to `display: inline-block`.
Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lefuw/1/edit?css,output) to show them lining up correctly.